# How to change listview DataSet on Gallery drag?

Tags: android, listview, gallery

I have a gallery with custom views that represent categories, depending on which category of the gallery is selected the listview should display one dataset or another, it is working, but the dataset shown does not correspond with the category selected,

Here is the adapter for the gallery:

```
public class GalleryViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<TreeNode> mNodes;
private HomeFragment mFrag;
private ListView mList;

public GalleryViewAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<TreeNode> mNodes, HomeFragment mFrag, ListView galleryList) {
    mContext = c;
    this.mNodes = mNodes;
    this.mFrag = mFrag;
    mList = galleryList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNodes.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mNodes.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    TreeNode childNode = (TreeNode) mNodes.get(position);
    if (childNode.getReference() instanceof Categoria) {
        return Long.valueOf(((Categoria) mNodes.get(position).getReference()).idCat);
    } else {
        return Long.valueOf(((Contenido) mNodes.get(position).getReference()).idCon);
    }
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final TreeNode childNode = (TreeNode) mNodes.get(position);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    int screenWidth = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

    if (childNode.getReference() instanceof Categoria) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery_item, parent, false);
        }
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_gallery_item_imageview);
        TextView mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_gallery_item_textView);

        Categoria mCat = (Categoria) childNode.getReference();
        imageView.setImageBitmap(Tools.scaleImageInPixels(Tools.createBitmapFromBase64(mCat.icon64.getBytes()),
                screenWidth));
        mTextView.setText(mCat.nombreCat);

        int newHeight = mFrag.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() / 4;
        int orgWidth = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        int orgHeight = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

        int newWidth = ((int) Math.floor((orgWidth * newHeight) / orgHeight) / 2);

        imageView.setMaxHeight(newHeight);
        imageView.setMaxWidth(newWidth);

        GalleryListAdapter mListAdapter = new GalleryListAdapter(mFrag.getActivity(), childNode, mFrag);
        mList.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
    } else {

    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

And here is my galleryListViewAdapter

```
public class GalleryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private TreeNode mNode;
private HomeFragment mFrag;


public GalleryListAdapter(Context mContext, TreeNode mNode, HomeFragment mFrag) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mNode = mNode;
    this.mFrag = mFrag;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNode.getChildren().size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mNode.getChildren().get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    if (mNode.getReference() instanceof Categoria) {
        return Long.valueOf(((Categoria) mNode.getReference()).idCat);
    } else {
        return Long.valueOf(((Contenido) mNode.getReference()).idCon);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (mNode.getReference() instanceof Categoria) {
        mNode = (TreeNode) mNode.getChildren().get(position);
    }
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_carrousel_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView autorView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        Contenido mCon = (Contenido) mNode.getReference();
        autorView.setText(mCon.tituloCon);
        textView.setText("");

        imageView.setImageBitmap(Tools.scaleImage(Tools.getParentIconRecursive(mNode),
                (int) MainActivity.getInstance().getAttributeDimension(R.attr.listPreferredItemHeight)));

        int newHeight = mFrag.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() / 2;
        int orgWidth = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        int orgHeight = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

        int newWidth = ((int) Math.floor((orgWidth * newHeight) / orgHeight) / 2);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                newWidth, newHeight);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);


    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mFrag.goToNode(mNode);
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set an `OnItemSelectedListener` on your `Gallery` like this:

```
private Gallery.OnItemSelectedListener _scrollListener = new Gallery.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    //execute the method that refresh the listview
                    fillListView(position);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
    };
```